# Get proxy setting from browser( IE)

Tags: r, proxy

Is there way to get proxy options from browser(IE for example) on Windows using R?

Now i have to declare options in script :

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
opts <- list(
  proxy         = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 
  proxyusername = "a", 
  proxypassword = "a", 
  proxyport     = xxxx
)
getURL("http://www.google.com/", .opts = opts)
```

Its not bad but i need to change settings (if password changed for example) in all scripts.
Its will be great simple pull such setting from browser settings.

(I cant write this options into enviroment , because i use different pc)

Comment: Maybe `system("netsh winhttp show proxy", intern=TRUE)`?

Comment: Its return that i havent proxy, but in browser i have proxy configuration and need to use it.

Comment: I can get server and port using `shell('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings" | find /i "proxy"',intern=TRUE)`, but dont know where find username and pass